# Jenkins find matching line starting with x from returned sh command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

When creating a patch from jenkins I like to extract the name of the generated patch:

To generate the patch and catch the output I use:

```
def generated_patch_script_output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """"generatepatch_script ${params.some_param}""")
```

This outputs in the following format

```
Patch created
some text
patch filename: some_path_here
some more text
more
```

Im trying to extract the `some_path_here` text from the line that starts with `patch filename:`, the value of `some_path_here` will be different every run.

How does one find the line that is matching `patch filename:` , I was thinking if I can find that line i can just replace `patch filename:`  with an empty string and will be left with the wanted result.

Comment: You can use regex matcher for this: `def path_val = (generated_patch_script_output =~/patch filename: (.*)/)[0][1]`. Do this in a separate method and annotate the method with `@NonCPS`

Answer (score 0):

Here are few different ways of doing this.

```
// Using regex
def fileName1 = (generated_patch_script_output =~ 'patch filename: (.*)')[0][1]

// String operations      
def fileName2 = generated_patch_script_output.split('patch filename:')[1].split('\n')[0].trim()

// iterating
def fileName3 = generated_patch_script_output.split("\n").find { it.contains("patch filename:") }.replace('patch filename:', '').trim()
```